# Don't show div anymore after user closed it

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a simple floating div on the bottom right corner of my website

How can I check if the user already clicked to close it and in a new page reload don't show that floating div again to him since he already shown that he is not interested in that message. Is this possible at all? maybe with cookies or local storage?

My simple code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    var jsBox = jQuery('<div class="floatBox">Nice float box </div>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
    //more code like closing btn...
    jQuery('body').append(jsBox);
});

jQuery("span.closeBtn").click(function() {
    jQuery('div.floatBox').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: "maybe with cookies or local storage" <- you nailed it, now go do it!

Comment: I never worked before with cookies or local storage, can you give me an hint or example? :) thank you

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: -1 Since you *know* about one or more possible approaches, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: +1 because user really hasn't done anything wrong here.

Comment: @Aaron and it's a poor question *because* he/she *hasn't done anything*, as per the close vote I put in. This is not a "specific problem" it is a "task". I am not sure why such sorts of questions are upvoted (even if you don't downvote, *don't upvote* and encourage such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For web storage, you should use `localStorage.foo`

This is a very simple **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tUmFz/3/)** of how web storage works.

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {   
   if(localStorage.blue !== '1') {
    $(this).addClass('blue');
       alert("this hasn't been clicked before");
       localStorage.blue='1';
    }  
});
```

Comment: thanks, this was the best solution for my example :)

Comment: You're welcome. It's an overly simplified example, but they're always the best ones ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
//dom ready
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    if(!localStorage.shown) {
        var jsBox = jQuery('<div class="floatBox">Nice float box </div>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
        //more code like closing btn...
        jQuery('body').append(jsBox);
    }

    jQuery("span.closeBtn").click(function() {
        jQuery('div.floatBox').fadeOut(200);
        localStorage.shown = true;
    });

});
```

Comment: this works well. This has support in all recent browsers? thanks

Comment: Doesn't webstorage only support strings?

Answer (score 1):

A server's side setting would be better than a cookie or localstorage, obviously but for a quick&dirty solution, both of those options are OK...

Using cookies, for instance: [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) is very simple to use (you can deal with cookies directly, but as usual, some smart people already covered the main browser differences...)

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    if(!$.cookie('hideFloatBox', Boolean)){
        var jsBox = jQuery('<div class="floatBox">Nice float box </div>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
        //more code like closing btn...
        jQuery('body').append(jsBox);
    }
});

jQuery("span.closeBtn").click(function() {
    jQuery('div.floatBox').fadeOut(200);
    $.cookie('hideFloatBox', true);
});
```

Comment: cool. Thanks. Should I put the closing function inside the page load or it's ok outside?

Comment: It depends where you script is :) The browser is handling code (HTML or JS in an HTML script tag) as it comes, so if you put your click handler before the span.closeBtn has been 'created' (parsed) by the browser, then the jQuery selector will return an empty array of selected elements and nothing will be bound to the click event. That's why it's so common to do stuff in a callback to window.load or as a short hand, $(function(){ //do stuff when DOM ready });, this way you don't need to worry.